# forms authentication for asp on iis 5

Tags: asp-classic, iis-5

I have website running under iis 5 which is built in asp. is it possible to have forms authentication using windows credentials so I can bypass explicit login to this website ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible. a 5 second Google earch showed [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310344/en-us)

you have to turn on Integrated Windows authentication